# Row count discrepancy between Intersect and Except queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, intersect, except

I'm getting some strange behaviour using intersect and except. Tb1 has the least rows out of the two tables, and the difference in row count between tb1 and the intersect query results is 143 (intersect = 9782, tb1 = 9925).
But when I run the same query with except, it returns 24 lines. My understanding is that it should have returned 143 rows, being the rows that didn't match in the intersect query. Could someone help me understand why this might be?

There is a possibility that both datasets have multiple duplicate rows (being subset data). Could this be the cause of the difference?

```
SELECT 
    amount
    ,date
FROM tb1
INTERSECT 
SELECT
    amount
    ,date
 FROM tb2
```

Comment: The `INTERSECT` query will return the same record of both table. Your data not show here. please provide with data so i find out the problem.

Comment: Yes, it can.  Doubles are also excluded by intersect / except oper. You should compare to DISTINCT counts.

Answer (score 1):

As you're probably already aware, the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is that the former returns a unique result, while the latter doesn't.

The same can be said about `INTERSECT` versus `INTERSECT ALL`.
And also about `EXCEPT` versus `EXCEPT ALL`.

So when there are dups, then the totals can be different from what you expect.

Here's a simplified demo to illustrate.

> ```
> create table TableA (
>  col1 int not null, 
>  col2 varchar(8)
> );
>
> create table TableB (
>  col1 int not null, 
>  col2 varchar(8)
> );
>
> insert into TableA (Col1, Col2) values
>   (1,'A')                -- only A
> , (3,'AB')               -- 1 in both
> , (4,'AAB'), (4,'AAB')   -- 2 in A, 1 in B
> , (5,'ABB')              -- 1 in A, 2 in B
> , (6,'AABB'), (6,'AABB') -- 2 in both
> , (7, NULL);             -- 1 NULL in both
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into TableB (Col1, Col2) values
>   (2,'B')                -- only B
> , (3,'AB')               -- 1 in both
> , (4,'AAB')              -- 2 in A, 1 in B
> , (5,'ABB'), (5,'ABB')   -- 1 in A, 2 in B
> , (6,'AABB'), (6,'AABB') -- 2 in both
> , (7, null);             -- 1 NULL in both
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select Col1, Col2 from TableA
> intersect
> select Col1, Col2 from TableB
> order by Col1, Col2
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | :---
>    3 | AB  
>    4 | AAB 
>    5 | ABB 
>    6 | AABB
>    7 | null
> ```

> ```
> select Col1, Col2 from TableA
> intersect all
> select Col1, Col2 from TableB
> order by Col1, Col2
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | :---
>    3 | AB  
>    4 | AAB 
>    5 | ABB 
>    6 | AABB
>    6 | AABB
>    7 | null
> ```

> ```
> select Col1, Col2 from TableA
> except 
> select Col1, Col2 from TableB
> order by Col1, Col2
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | :---
>    1 | A
> ```

> ```
> select Col1, Col2 from TableA
> except all
> select Col1, Col2 from TableB
> order by Col1, Col2
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | :---
>    1 | A   
>    4 | AAB
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b38aad78b96790030a85938ea45d75dd)*